# MVC 5 Entity Framework 6 community based app

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6

I am completely new to MVC and EF ( coming from web forms ) so I apologize up front if this question is dumb ;)

I need to build an app that a user logs into using AspIdentity that also ties to a Community table. Once logged in they can only see data that is community specific site wide. I have the app built but I am struggling with how it will only pull data based on a Community ID... In web forms I would build all this logic myself :/

Basically there are the built in Identity tables and the ones I defined ( Community, Homes, Residents etc. )

Seems like a simple app and it is but I dont see any tutorials that do this.

Thanks!

Comment: Alter the `ApplicationUser` model to include a reference to `Community`

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/10/16/customizing-profile-information-in-asp-net-identity-in-vs-2013-templates.aspx

Comment: Thanks.. I think I am struggling with how simple things are in MVC as opposed to how web forms work.

Answer (score 0):

You can approach it from two ways. If the user only ever belongs to one community, then you can simply use the user's community to restrict your queries. Essentially, you'll do something like:

```
var foo = db.Foos.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Id == id && m.CommunityId = user.CommunityId);
if (foo == null)
{
    return new HttpNotFoundResponse();
}
```

In other words, you just add an additional condition when pulling items from your database to match the user's community. That way, the user will only ever see something other than a 404 if it belongs to their community.

Option 2 is to make the community part of the URL, and use that to restrict your queries similar to the above. For example, you might have something like `/awesome-community/foo`. Then, in the action that serves that you'd have something like:

```
public ActionResult Foo(string community)
{
    ...
```

And, again, you'd just limit the query by that community as above. If you follow this approach, though, you will probably then need to also do something like create a custom `Authorize` attribute that verifies that your user actually belongs to the community.

Comment: Thanks. Where do these queries live in MVC?

Comment: In your actions. Basically wherever you pull something out of the database that is community-specific, you pass the community id from the user, URL, whatever along for the ride to condition the query. If nothing is returned, that means the user doesn't have access or the object doesn't belong to the specific community being viewed.

Comment: Ok. I dont see any queries that look like that.

Comment: I'm apparently not being clear. Imagine you're listing `Homes` for the particular community. Instead of just doing something `var homes = db.Homes`, you'd do `var homes = db.Homes.Where(m => m.CommunityId == communityId)`. So now, you're only showing what actually belongs to the community.

Comment: I get that part, the only queries I see in my project are like this:   // GET: Homes
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View(db.Home.ToList());
        }

Comment: So what you are saying is I can replace that code with custom query code and control it that way?

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would tackle it, and see if it at least gets you rolling. I'm taking a clean MVC web project that comes with Visual Studio:

[image: VisualStudio -- New MVC Project]

I'll also be borrowing the community concept from StackOverflow where you have types of visitors, and content that is applicable. (In the example's case, "Programmers" have their set of questions, while "Designers" have their set.)

An finally, for brevity, I've tried to exclude portion of the files I'm not modifying. To keep things short, existing code has been replaced with a `Snip` comment.

Onward!

### Infrastructure

Setup the additional entities that give us a Community and data specific to that community (Question).

```
public class Community
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class Question
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Community Community { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

Add these entities to the `ApplicationUser` as well as to the `ApplicationDbContext`.

`~/Models/IdentityModels.cs`:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Community Community { get; set; }

    /* Snip */
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public DbSet<Community> Communities { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    /* Snip */
}
```

Attach the community to the user. Claims make this really easy since we're just attaching additional information to the user profile. Furthermore, the Visual Studio folks already created a placeholder for us.

```
// This makes it easier to reference and makes sure we're consistent
public static class CustomClaimTypes
{
    public const string CommunityId = "http://stackoverflow.com/claims/communityid";
}

public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
    public virtual Community Community { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        userIdentity.AddClaim(new Claim(CustomClaimTypes.CommnunityId, this.CommunityId.ToString()));
        return userIdentity;
    }
}
```

*Note that we've added `userIdentity.AddClaim(...)` (and our static class).*

### Presentation

Modify the view model to accommodate our change.

`~/Models/AccountViewModels.cs`:

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    /* snip */

    [Required]
    [Display(Name = "Community")]
    public int CommunityId { get; set; }
}
```

Plumb this into our Controller.

`~/Controllers/AccountController.cs`:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Register()
{
    ViewBag.Communities = GetCommunities();

    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        /* Snip */
    }
    ViewBag.Communities = GetCommunities();
    return View(model);
}

// The additional method we're calling above:
private IEnumerable<SelectListItem> GetCommunities()
{
    var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
    var communities = db.Communities.ToDictionary(k => k.Id, v => v.Name);
    return communities.Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
        Text = c.Value,
        Value = c.Key.ToString()
    });
}
```

Flush it out through our view.

`~/Views/Account/Register.cshtml`:

```
@* Snip *@
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.CommunityId, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CommunityId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.Communities, new { @class = "form-control" })
    </div>
</div>
@* Snip *@
```

Create a new action the Home controller:

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Questions()
{
    var communityId = GetCommunityId();
    var db = ApplicationDbContext.Create();
    var community = db.Communities.SingleOrDefault(c => c.Id == communityId);
    var questions = db.Questions.Where(c => c.CommunityId == communityId).AsEnumerable();

    ViewBag.Message = community.Name;
    return View(questions);
}

// Helper that's probably better suited in a more common location
private Int32 GetCommunityId()
{
    var communityIdClaim = ((ClaimsPrincipal)User).Claims
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == CustomClaimTypes.CommnunityId);
    Int32 communityId;
    return communityIdClaim != null && Int32.TryParse(communityIdClaim.Value, out communityId)
        ? communityId
        : -1; // Erroneous id
}
```

And a view to go with it:

```
@model IEnumerable<@* Your.Model.Namespace. *@Question>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Questions";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Question</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach (var question in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td>@question.Title</td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Add a link to your menu.

`~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml

```
@* Snip *@
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    @* Snip *@
    <li>@Html.ActionLink("Questions", "Questions", "Home")</li>
</ul>
@* Snip *@
```

### Sample Content

Create a very basic `DbInitializer` that will populate some info we can use. So, back to the `~/ModelsIdentityModels.cs` file:

```
public class ApplicationDbInitializer : CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        var communities = new[]{
            new Community { Name = "Programmers" },
            new Community { Name = "Designers" }
        };

        var questions = new[]{
            new Question { Community = communities[0], Title = "How do I write my first application?" },
            new Question { Community = communities[0], Title = "What is unit testing?" },
            new Question { Community = communities[0], Title = "Inversion of Control: What is it?" },

            new Question { Community = communities[1], Title = "What is a StyleSheet?" },
            new Question { Community = communities[1], Title = "HTML5: What do I need to know?" },
            new Question { Community = communities[1], Title = "Is Silverlight still being used?" },
        };

        context.Communities.AddRange(communities);
        context.Questions.AddRange(questions);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    // for simplicity, let's add a static ctor within the context
    static ApplicationDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new ApplicationDbInitializer());
    }

    /* Snip */
}
```

### Give it a run-through

Now you should be able to register a user, and see content that's applicable to the community they're a part of:

#### Paul (the Programmer)

[image: Paul - Register]
[image: Paul - Questions List]

#### Debby (the Designer)

[image: Debby - Register]
[image: Debby - Questions List]

Comment: Thanks for the kick start ;)  I'll give it a shot.

Comment: yw. The claims are nice to use, but may not be necessary for your application. You can do this a multitude of different ways, this is just one option. I just find a Claim (and tied to the authenticated user) is a safe bet.

Comment: basically this app will have Community with many homes and homes have many residents, additional tables will be used but that's the basic design.

Comment: Are you allowing the possibility of a user to switch communities?

Comment: No. Just an administration section where they can be added or deleted

Comment: So for migrations sake will this be all in one or will many migrations need to be set up for each entity?

Comment: No need, it can be done per entity or in batches. I typical create one immediately with just identify framework as is, then create one for every functional piece (initial setup of models for example).

Comment: Basically, each time you'd migrate live is s great time to create a migration (as you'll need it to run on a different server).

Comment: Brad, in this demo you have created are the ID fields auto incremented? ( IsIdentity ). Im struggling with EF 6 and how to accomplish easy tasks like have a DateCreated field that has a default value of GetDate(). Im too used to writing all the DB stuff myself :)

Comment: Ef has in implicit convention it follows for properties based on their name. So to answer your question, yes they will be audio increment columns, unless specified otherwise (through model binding or entity type configuration). I hope that's the information you're after.

Comment: Oh, and add fat as default value, when you scaffold the migration to add these entities, you have the ability to customize, at the database level, what will be used via that configuration class. This is where you'd define that you want to use SQLS native date.

Comment: Thanks Brad. I sent you an invite to connect on LinkedIn this morning. Wanted to discuss MVC with you a little further and offline.

Comment: I am trying to build this from scratch following along with what you posted here, I have a question. Why did you set the CommunityID to this?   public const string CommunityId = "http://stackoverflow.com/claims/communityid";

Comment: Need to define a claim type is a consistent manner, because you need to use that string any time you want the stored claim. This just ensures no typos,and allows you to easily refractor it later if need be.